# Kotlin - mutableList always returns empty list

Tags: list, kotlin

I'm using a range with an inline transform so that I can have a list of values and that I want to send it to a method in forEach. But, somehow I see that is not happening. This is the example code I'm using

```
var valuesList: List<Test> = mutableListOf()
(1..5).map {
    valuesList.plus(Test(<curr value>, Instant.now())
    // Have a condition to check the value and using the value in next statement
    valuesList.plus(Test(<prev value>, Instant.now())
}.forEach { <expecting a list here to send to a method> }
```

Somehow I always see valuesList as empty list. Can anyone let me know the mistake I'm doing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "// Have a condition ...." please show this condition.

Comment: @user3497321 Sergio is right: you should post the condition. It does not make a lot of sense to use _(1..5).map_ to add values to a mutableList, you would be better off to either use a for loop, or to combine the creation of _valuesList_ and the _map_ into one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add items to `List`, try to change it to `MutableList`, also you need to use `.add()` to add items to the list not `.plus()`, `.plus()` is going to return a new list not adding items to the old one.

so your code should look like this :

```
val valuesList: MutableList<Test> = mutableListOf()
(1..5).map {
    valuesList.add(Test(<curr value>, Instant.now())
    // Have a condition to check the value and using the value in next statement
    valuesList.add(Test(<prev value>, Instant.now())
}.forEach { <expecting a list here to send to a method> }
```

Also `forEach` here is not going to receive `valuesList` so if you wan to iterate `valuesList`, iterate it separately after the map :

```
valuesList.forEach { }
```

Comment: Actually you can add elements to the `MutableList`.

Comment: yes I was talking about `List`

Comment: @Sergio OP assigned their `mutableListOf` result to a variable of type `List`

Comment: @Joffrey I see that, but there is an extension function `Collection<T>.plus(element: T)` that should work by creating a new list.

Comment: But OP doesn't use the return value of `plus` either

Comment: @Kaido - What you said is correct. I have added items to list and called ```forEach { }``` separately. That has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. You've created a mutable list, but assigned it to an immutable list. Change `List<Test>` to `MutableList<Test>`

   ```kotlin
   var valuesList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
   ```

   You should probably also make it a `val`, not a `var`. You want to change the contents of the list, not the variable that points to the list.

   ```kotlin
   val valuesList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
   ```
2. [`plus()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) is an operator function that combines two lists, and returns the result. It does NOT change the lists that are being provided.

   ```kotlin
     .map {

       // this `plus` returns a new list
       valuesList.plus(Test(<curr value>, Instant.now())


       // Have a condition to check the value and using the value in next statement
       valuesList.plus(Test(<prev value>, Instant.now())
     }
   ```

   [`plusAssign()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-assign.html) is the one you want - it appends the values of the second list onto the first

   ```kotlin
     valuesList.plusAssign("<current>")
   ```

   Because `plusAssign()` is an operator function, it means we can use `+=` to make it clear. Then we can work with lists just like how we would work with integers.

   ```kotlin
     // the string will be appended to the end of the list
     valuesList += "<current>"
   ```

   See more: [Kotlin docs on plus and minus operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-plus-minus.html)
3. It looks unusual that you're 'mapping' 1 to 5, but not using the integer, and additionally looping over the result.

   Without further details I can't say much (please update your question with more code if you want more information). But from what you've shown I think you can use an [initializer function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists) to build an immutable list in one go:

   ```kotlin
   // create a size-5 list, with elements e1, e2, e3, e4, e5
   val valuesList: List<String> = List(5) { i ->
     "e$i"
   }
   ```

   I can also recommend the [collection builder functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#create-with-collection-builder-functions).

Comment: Will try this. I've used ```plus``` and ```plusElement``` and both didn't work. I'll try ```plusAssign```.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to construct *valuesList* in one go. Something along this (not knowing more about the condition):

```
import java.time.Instant

data class Test(val value: Any, val now: Instant)

val valuesList: List<Test> = (1..5)
  .flatMap { i ->
    val value1 = Test(i, Instant.now())
    val condition = true   // calculate the condition to true or false here
    val value2 = if (condition) Test(i, Instant.now()) else null
    listOfNotNull(value1, value2)
  }

valuesList.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: I have tried this, somehow did't work, will explore more. Thank you.